# To create and alloc UITableView depending on array count

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a NSMutableArray walkArray which contains another array walkSteps. I want to create number of uitableview depending on walArray count.

The table should look like:
if array count is 2 then
table 1:
Walk to road1
steps 1
steps 2
steps 3

table 2:
walk to road 2
steps 1
steps 2
steps 3
steps 4

The table should be on same view.
If any one has any idea please help.
Thank you.

Comment: You can use tableview as sectioned table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think You can refer [Group table](http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/iphone/iphone-uitableview-tutorial-grouped-table/)/ [section table](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TheElements/Introduction/Intro.html)